# How do I use getOutputStream() and getWriter() in the same servlet request?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, netbeans, outputstream

How do I use getOutputStream() and getWriter() in the same servlet request?

Comment: Please provide more detail. In particular, are you talking about some requests being handled using getWriter and some being handled with getOutputStream, or are you trying to use them both for the same request?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't use them both at the same time. If you first did `getOutputStream()` you can't consequently in the same request do `getWriter()` and vice versa. You can however wrap your `ServletOuptputStream` in a `PrintWriter` to get the same kind of writer you would have from `getWriter()`.

```
ServletOutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
// Notice encoding here, very important that it matches that of
// response.setCharacterEncoding();
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(out, "utf-8"));
```

Another solution to not using `getWriter()` is to use a `PrintStream` which is somewhat similar, but then you don't have type compatibility with `Writer` or `PrintWriter`.

```
// Encoding again very important to match that of your output.
PrintStream print = new PrintStream(os, true, "utf-8");
```

Comment: how can i use getwriter for printing the chart in jfreechart?

Comment: @Parith, post that as a new question instead.

Answer (score 3):

You can use them both, just not at the same time, or rather not for the same response. If you need to use a Writer after you've already started using the OutputStream, just wrap an OutputStreamWriter around the output stream. However if you need to use an output stream after you've already used the writer you can't. You could always get the output stream first, wrap the writer around it as above, do your Writing, flush, then do your output streaming.